# How can I open an image from file system into UIImage View

Tags: ios, iphone, image, uiimageview

Before anyone down votes my question, I have literally looked all over stack and cannot find the answer

I am making a phonegap app which I can place an image into my filesystem

the url :

```
file:///Users/danielnasello/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/75EE3563-560D-4CFD-B357-313DD559573D/Documents/Vault/1386252707450.jpg
```

I can then pass this url to my modal controller to present an image in the image view.
the problem is I cannot seem to find the correct way to access the image from my filesystem and display it into my image view.

my current relevant code 
(self.myImage) is the string i pass from phonegap. it does contain the url string because I am logging it, so I know the url is getting passed. However, the image simply will not display.
I tried using image named from one of my library images and it works fine. I just cant seem to find the correct way to present it using file url.

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.myImage];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

  self.imageView.image= img;
```

Answer (score 4):

here is the code for that.

```
NSString *filepath=[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1386252707450.jpg"];
self.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
```

Comment: here is what you said "I can then pass this url to my modal controller to present an image in the image view. the problem is I cannot seem to find the correct way to access the image from my filesystem and display it into my image view"  the code i gave you just need to know the (image name saved) in any view controller and you with this name you can get image anywhere by this code and it works

Comment: I get it. But this is not a pure IOS app. This is an app that was made in PhoneGap that I made an extension for. So i have to initially pass the file uri from the webview to the modal. However I cannot directly access the image uri because i present the images in hTML/JS which is the cause for the entire headache.

Answer (score -1):

this code is actually correct. It just doesn't work on simulators (shocker), you need a real device